# create empty stream and add elements to it

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to have a stream where I can put elements after creation:

```
Stream<Task> all2 = Stream.of();
```

Because the return type of the method is also a Stream and I want to avoid the extra cost by using a list and the need for `return list.stream()`:

```
Stream<Task> getAll(){
    Stream<Task> all2 = Stream.of();

    all2.add(item1);
    ..

    return all2
}
```

But how can I add elements to `all2` for further processing?

Is this the only way to do this:

```
Stream<Task> all2 = Stream.of();
all2 = Stream.concat(all2, Stream.of(new Task("hello")));
...
all2 = Stream.concat(all2, Stream.of(new Task("hello_1000000")));
```

Is this really cheaper than using a list and add elements to it?

```
List<Task> all = new ArrayList<>();
all.add(new Task("hello");
...
all.add(new Task("hello_1000000");
return all.stream();
```

Comment: "*Is this really cheaper than using a list and add elements to it?*" - no, why do you think so? And why not just use collections and then use `Stream` for what it was designed for - processing elements, instead of being a collection?

Comment: why do you think so? because no need to materialize elements to a list only to convert it back to a stream.

Comment: "*because no need to materialize elements to a list only to convert it back to a stream*" - yes, there is a need. The exact above example. It's not so clear what you're trying to achieve and why the *typical* approach does not satisfy you.

Comment: There is also a Stream.Builder. Might be exactly what you need. Or not.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn yes, you are right. Did not see that. Please anwer the question. I would accept this as the perfect answer for this topic (`build.add(new Task()`)

Comment: Just return a collection from your method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the perfect case for a [Stream.Builder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.Builder.html)

```
Stream<Task> getAll(){
    Stream.Builder<Task> all2 = Stream.builder();

    all2.add(item1);
    ..

    return all2.build();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Reading the comments you probably need a `Stream` of infinitely generated elements. `Stream::generate` does that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        getStream()
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    static String getUserInput(Scanner scanner) {
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }

    static Stream<String> getStream() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        return Stream.generate(() -> getUserInput(sc)).takeWhile(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty));
    }
}
```

With this approach you have a `Stream<String>`, which will wait for the user to input elements (inifitely, or up to the first error or `empty()` String) and apply the stream operations to every element (in this case, `forEach` - as shown in `main()`).